# Best way to get the data from Action subclass to Jsp View?

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, struts

I am trying to pass a list of some data by storing each item's data in a HashMap and then storing all the HashMaps in a ArrayList and then passing it to the request object to the View.

Can anybody tell me a better way to do so!

One more thing I would like to add is that sometimes the data I want to put first is null and so the ArrayList size becomes zero.

Comment: @Lokesh,Could you post some snippet of code.

Comment: I can't give the exact code but here is some for your review :

Comment: ArrayList ItemsList =new ArrayList();

Comment: //Get ResultSet by executeQuery()

Comment: HashMap mp=new HashMap(); //Store data in the HashMap ;  ItemsList.add(mp); }

Answer (score 0):

Have the below code in ActionClass as below
`request.setAttribute("ItemsList",ItemsList);//set it in request scope`

and fetch it in the coressponding jsp page by using the below snippet
`request.getAttribute("ItemsList"); //get it via request scope`

Please let me know if its working.

Possible alternate solution is to iterate the list using the `<logic:iterate>` struts tag.

Comment: Actually i have been using the code you just wrote. The problem is when there are null values at the first row of data. That means when i put the data into HashMap then it becomes a problem when i try to access it in Jsp page. Any way to actually avoid this way. Also is there any way to use JstL or Struts tags to display this data on the view ?

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach also :

As you said you are putting all the hashmap data into the list, first do one thing. Put that list as a field into the ActionForm. After that set that list from the action class. for example if you have the employees you will have the method like setEmployees().
So you can set the list as empForm.setEmployees(employeeList); and all this will be in your action class.

Next, form jsp page you can retrieve the values as  ${empForm.employees}